# How can I order integer string, floating number and with special characters

Tags: javascript, sorting

Please help, i new in javascript thx.

```
let test = [" 1/2", " 3/4", " 1", " 1.1/4", " 1.1/2", " 2", " 2.1/2", " 3", " 4", " 3/8", " 1/4"];
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to do, what you have done, and what the issue is.

Comment: Are you trying to convert integers and floating point numbers to strings?

Comment: Thanks for writing, it happens that I am trying to order valve measurements, the arrangement comes in the form of a rope. But I don't know how to order with floating number and integers. It should be from highest to lowest like this:
two
3
4 
6 
1
1.1 / 2
1.1 / 4
1/2
2.1 / 2
3/4

Comment: @MediEle, do you have an explanation of the wanted order? is the list complete in the comment?

Answer (score 1):

You could evaluate the delta.

```js
let test = [" 1/2", " 3/4", " 1", " 1.1/4", " 1.1/2", " 2", " 2.1/2", " 3", " 4", " 3/8", " 1/4"];

test.sort((a, b) => eval(`${a} - ${b}`));

console.log(...test);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I must order like this
3
4
6
one
1.1 / 2
1.1 / 4
1/2
2.1 / 2
3/4

Answer (score 1):

@Nina's solution is nice and simple, but some people like to avoid eval.

If so, the data you have provided is nice and simple to parse, so the below is another option.

```js
let test = [" 1/2", " 3/4", " 1", " 1.1/4", " 1.1/2", " 2", " 2.1/2", " 3", " 4", " 3/8", " 1/4"];

const val = str => { const [a,b = 1] = str.split('/'); return a / b };

test.sort((a, b) => val(a)-val(b));

console.log(...test);
```

Comment: thanks for replying, but the numbers should be ordered like this

2 3 4 6 1 1.1 / 2 1.1 / 4 1/2 2.1 / 2 3/4

from high to low, plis help :(